# Extended WPF Toolkit - ChildWindow do not allow focus parent

Tags: c#, wpf, childwindow

I have a ChildWindow that overlays a view that has inputs and buttons. If the ChildWindow is opened i am not able to click any of the buttons which is good. But with *TAB* i am able to switch the focus and select one of the buttons and hit enter.

Any idea how I can prevent this?

Any help is appreciated...

The code is really simple and nothing special...

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <xctk:ChildWindow Name="chWindow" IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World ..." />
    </xctk:ChildWindow>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Load" Click="OnLoadClicked"/>
        <Button Content="Re-Initialize" Click="OnInitClicked"/>
        <Button Content="Modal dialog" Click="OnModalClicked" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, IModuleManager moduleManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
        this.ConfirmationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>();

        this.moduleCatalog = moduleCatalog;
        this.moduleManager = moduleManager;

        UpdateModulesList();

        this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.chWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: show us some code.. How you launch window? Then it will be helpful to give some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: try setting [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx) to Cycle on the child window; this should be a much better solution.

You could try handling the PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event and simply not allowing it through; this should keep focus in your child window.

Comment: Okay but wouldnt it then also be disabled for the child window or do you mean handle the focus lost of the ChildWindow?

Comment: I did mean to handle it on the child window, but that's not to say it won't have problems of its own. I can't really remember how all the focus events interact in WPF - perhaps preview events will tunnel down and you will get it when any control in the child window loses focus, so you'd need to check who the sender is. If you're still having problems, let me know and I'll fire up visual studio to actually try things :)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out 

Comment: See update; sorry about not remembering this stuff sooner, it's been a while since I've worked with WPF :)

Comment: Thanks for the update...

Your solution works. What I have to do is set the focus to the child window explicitly after it is shown.